# How exactly does theme inheritance work in Android?

Tags: android

I have the following theme in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If I remove the `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` line, my activities have the titlebar on them. However, if I keep that line there, then they do not have a titlebar (which is what I want).

I'm curious why `parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` seems to have no effect? Does `parent` not do what I think it does? I thought it worked like this:

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --> AppBaseTheme --> AppTheme
^                                   ^                ^
|                                   |                |
|                                   |                Has everything AppBaseTheme
|                                   |                does, unless it's overridden
|                                   |
|                                   Has everything @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
|                                   does, unless it's overridden (which I'm not
|                                   doing)
|
Sets whatever it needs to to not have a title, which I assume
is done by setting <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

However, I've also found that if I set `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in `AppBaseTheme` it also has no effect; I have to set it in `AppTheme`. Then what the heck is the point of specifying the parent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I just figured it out. It turns out that when I created the project, Android created a `res/values-14/styles.xml` file, and inside of that was `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">`.

It turns out that the `res/values-14/styles.xml` file was overriding my default `res/values/styles.xml` because the device I was testing on has API level 14, and thus it preferred the files in `values-14` than the default `values`.

Inheritance does seem to work like I thought it did; I just wasn't realizing things were being overridden by the files created when I first made my project.

Comment: I realised I had a v21 styles file, but I assumed, like productFlavours for example, Android would merge the 2 style files. But as you pointed out the v21 will simply take precedence. So any style items that need to be common in a style declaration that exists in both style files must be declared in both. I.e. if your style has v21 specific styles and therefore must appear in your v21 styles.xml file, then must you duplicate all the style items for that style in each file!